# Код в pygame не завершается, хотя я прописываю проверку и на отдельном тестовом коде все работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Пишу как обычно

```py
while True:
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
```

Но выход не работает. Код большой, не работает ни в одном из мест, то когда я создаю маленький пример для теста, все прекрасно закрывается. Пробую по-разному, exit, quit или через sys, но не помогает. С чем это может быть связано?

Ред.: Сейчас заметил, что кнопка выхода перестала работать даже в моих старых проектах, хотя раньше все было ок. Я в недоумении.

Ред2: Черт побери, все снова работает, хотя я ничего не менял! Жеваный крот! Теперь я еще больше нуждаюсь в пояснениях

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте записать эту часть кода в таком виде:

```
run = True
while run:
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Пиши break, и у тебя завершится цикл
2. Если ты всё-таки хочешь выйти из программы, то подключи библиотеку sys и вместо exit(), пиши sys.exit()